# Sympy subs vs replace vs xreplace

Tags: python, sympy

What is the difference between subs, replace, and xreplace in sympy?

I have been using subs for substitution of symbolics. I was discussing with someone and they recommended using replace instead of subs for most cases. Then I also stumbled on xreplace.

For my application I am substituting an expression in for a variable. Is one of these recommended over the other for that? What are the main uses for each? Which one would generally be recommended?

Comment: Is there something wrong or incomplete about the docs for the 3 functions?  They reference each other.

Comment: Could you send a link to replace and xreplace please? I couldn't seem to find them.

Comment: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#module-sympy.core.basic documents the `replace`, `subs` and `xreplace` methods.